# ANTLR4 parsing a keyword-contained variable name

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grammar

I'm trying to parse a simple integer declaration in antlr4.
The grammar I'm doing now is:

```
main  : 'int' var '=' NUMBER+ ;
var   : LETTER (LETTER | NUMBER)* ;
LETTER: [a-zA-Z_] ;
NUMBER: [0-9] ;
WS    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When I tried to test the main rule with `int int_A = 0`, I got an error:

> extraneous input 'int' expecting LETTER.

I know it's because the variable name 'int_A' contains the keyword 'int', but how do I modify my grammar? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lexer creates tokens with as much characters as possible. So `int_A` is being tokenised as the following 3 tokens:

- `'int'` (int keyword defined in parser)
- `LETTER` (`_`)
- `LETTER` (`A`)

So the parser cannot create a `var` with these tokens.

Instead of a parser rule `var`, make it a lexer rule:

```
main   : 'int' VAR '=' NUMBER+ ;
VAR    : [a-zA-Z_] ([a-zA-Z_] | [0-9])* ;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
WS     : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This answer also clear up my misconception about parser programming.

Comment: You're welcome @CarloChuang, note that you also want to do `NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;` and not: `NUMBER : [0-9] ;`